# Speech hotword to active listening with Google Speech API

Tags: go, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, speech

I'm currently in the works of building a small app with [Googles Speech API Alpha](https://cloud.google.com/speech/) and am trying to find a solid solution for creating a "hotword". Essentially I don't to be constantly sending recorded data to Google to wait for a hotword, nor do I want to have to physically press a button to active listening. Are there any offline speech to text solutions that can be usable to listen for that single word before it starts recording data to send to Google?

Comment: I'm researching the same thing. One option is to roll your own neural network using something like tensorflow and following this paper: https://papers.nips.cc/paper/3674-unsupervised-feature-learning-for-audio-classification-using-convolutional-deep-belief-networks.pdf

Comment: A python solution would be https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis/